# Avoid dynamic_cast when passing base class as a param to a virtual function

Tags: c++, inheritance, derived-class, virtual-functions, dynamic-cast

I couldn't find a definite answer to this simple, yet important case. (I'd appreciate if someone will refer me to an answer).

Lets say I have two kinds of inheritance: Class A which is the base class of Class B, and class C which is the Base class of Class D, and do extra work (knowing it's actually a pointer to D).

Now lets say class A has a virtual function 'foo' which takes as a parameter a pointer to C. What I'd like to achieve is whenever A calls 'foo', it would acts as if it got a pointer to C, and whenever B calls foo, it would act as if it got a pointer to D.

The compiler would allow me to pass an object which was initialized like: **C* c = new D();**, but within 'foo', as far as I can tell, there no way to tell that we actually got a pointer to D without using dynamic_cast.

Here's a sketch of what I'm thinking of:

```
class C {};
class D : C {// has more functions };


class A {

public:
    virtual void foo (C* c) { //do something with c* };

};


class B : A {

public

    virtual void foo (C* c) { // call A::foo()
                              //do something with c knowing that c* as actually a D*
                             }

};
```

It seems inevitable to using dynamic_cast within B::foo in order to achieve what I want. I know that generally speaking using dynamic_cast suggests bad OOP design as it could violate LSP, but I can't think of other ways to accomplish what I want.

I'd love to hear some offers - maybe how would one change the design, or even 'dynamic_cast is necessary' will be OK.

I hope I made my point clear, if not - I'll clarify my question.

Update: Maybe I've should have mention it before (and b.t.w I'm not just making this up, I actually had to program something like this in University), but the idea that a fifth class, say E will hold an array (or list or whatever) of type A, and I have an algorihm which iterates over this array, and for
each element there it should call this 'foo' method - where in case the class was actually A*, it should operate like before, and if it is B*, it should perform the 'foo' of class B.

Something like this:

```
//within class E
A** arrayOfAs; //(and B's)
for (int i = 0 ; i < lengthOfArray ; ++i ) 
{
    arrayOfAs[i]->foo(/*someObject*/);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you realise you are using private inheritance? There can be no LSP here.

Comment: _'Avoid dynamic_cast when passing base class ...'_ Choose a better design, the question smells already ...

Answer (score 1):

To do what you want, you'd need a `dynamic_cast` in `B::foo`.
But... if you can only call `B::foo` with a `D`, the function
shouldn't overload `A::foo`.  Doing so violates LSP, and more or
less defeats the purpose of object oriented code.